# SSRS multi-value parameter using a stored procedure has too many values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on a SSRS report that uses a stored procedure containing a few parameters.

1 of the paramaters I am having problems with is because I have the option of selecting more than one item (guid values) and they are exceeding 4000+ comma separated values.

Store Procedure: proc_GetCompanyRecord

========================================

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetCompanyRecord]
    (
    @Year AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CoreCompanyId AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CompanyId AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OwnerId VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    )

--THE REST OF MY QUERY HERE WHICH PULLS ALL OF THE NEEDED COLUMNS

WHERE CoreCompany.CoreCompanyId in (SELECT * FROM ufnSplit (@CoreCompanyId, ','))
AND Company.CompanyId in (SELECT * FROM ufnSplit (@CompanyId, ','))
```

========================================

Function: [dbo].[ufnSplit]

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSplit]
(
    @RepParam varchar(MAX),
    @Delim char(1)
)
RETURNS @Values TABLE (Item UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @chrind INT
  DECLARE @Piece varchar(MAX)
  SELECT @chrind = 1 
  WHILE @chrind > 0
    BEGIN
      SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim,@RepParam)
      IF @chrind  > 0
        SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@RepParam,@chrind - 1)
      ELSE
        SELECT @Piece = @RepParam
      INSERT  @Values(Item) VALUES(@Piece)
      SELECT @RepParam = RIGHT(@RepParam,LEN(@RepParam) - @chrind)
      IF LEN(@RepParam) = 0 BREAK
    END
  RETURN
  END
```

When I try to just run the stored procedure by providing 4000+ values to @CompanyId parameter, it works fine and return all possible records.

But after I deployed the report in CRM, run it and click on view report it shows the following error, "An error has occurred"

I diagnosed it and found that 4000+ guid comma saperated values are too much for store procedure and IN statement:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 7 String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

Please help!

Comment: You need to reevaluate your approach. What is the reason you are passing 4000+ character parameter to the report? Is it the user selecting multiple values or is it passed programmatically?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal not programmatically, it is just a SSRS report and have user selecting multiple values. we have 4000+ companies for '@CompanyId' parameter and user can select 'Select All' - Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

When you make your @CompanyID parameter query. Add an option for 'Select All'.

```
SELECT 'Select All' AS CompanyID, 1 as myOrder
 UNION
 Select CAST(CompanyID AS VARCHAR), 2 as myOrder
 FROM CompanyTable
 ORDER BY myOrder
```

With this the user doesn't have to select all 4000 values they can just select the 'Select All' option and it will select everything for them. And update your proc_getCompanyRecord to handle the new 'Select All' value of CompanyID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetCompanyRecord]
    (
    @Year AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CoreCompanyId AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CompanyId AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OwnerId VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    )

--THE REST OF MY QUERY HERE WHICH PULLS ALL OF THE NEEDED COLUMNS

WHERE CoreCompany.CoreCompanyId in (SELECT * FROM ufnSplit (@CoreCompanyId, ','))
AND (Company.CompanyId in (SELECT * FROM ufnSplit (@CompanyId, ',')) OR Company.CompanyID = 'Select All')
```